# Я выдал приложению разрешения, но разрешения были бесполезны до перезагрузки устройства

Tags: android, android-permissions

почему в android 11 разрешения для приложения вступают в силу только после перезагрузки устройства?

Само приложение не запрашивает разрешений, их выдача производится вручную. Такого бага нет в 7 и 13 android

Comment: [Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)